# Can't embed Facebook post into Next JS generated page

Tags: reactjs, facebook, next.js, embed

I am trying to embed a public FB post into the main page of my application. I am following FB guide and it's pretty simple. It works when I do it in .html file, but doesn't with Next JS.
Basically, instructions are that you need to insert this right after the body opening tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous"
  src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;autoLogAppEvents=1&amp;version=v9.0&amp;appId={appId}" nonce={someNonce}"></script>
```

and then you put the other part wherever you want.

I even created a custom _document.js file and included this script, I can also see it in the browser. But the post does not get loaded.

Anyone had this kind of issue?

Comment: If the elements you want to get replaced by the social plugins are not part of the DOM already when the SDK initializes, then you need to call https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Lakindu, add this useEffect to your code

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
  }, []);
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you already have the JS SDK loaded in your document, like you mentioned (you might also load the script on-demand via JavaScript if preferred).

```js
// pages/_document

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <!-- additional code -->
        <body>
          <!-- additional code -->
          <script
            async
            defer
            src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"
          />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

You can then render a Facebook post inside one of your components with:

```html
<div
    className="fb-post"
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/"
/>
```

For further details refer to the [official Embedded Posts documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/).

Comment: this does not work